# Speed up an interpolating function in a finite interval

Tags: performance-tuning

I want to evaluate a 2D interpolating function many times in a finite interval. What is the fastest way to do that?

*I imagine that its possible to specify a discrete grid and memoize the function on this grid. Afterwards round any input value to values on this grid and call the memoized function. But I am not sure if this is the most convenient and fastest way to do.*

Comment: I'd try `fInt=Interpolation[...,InterpolationOrder->0]` first, which is basically what you're describing. If that's not fast enough you can try to build your own version, but that might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Try using `Listable` functions first, because they are vectorized. Next try `Map`ping your functions, and last try `ParallelTable` to parallelise over cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InterpolationFunction`s are listable, but not in a very obvious way. Take the following example from the documentation:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, LCM[x, y]}, {x, 4}, {y, 4}], 1]
f = Interpolation[data]
```

Suppose we want to evaluate f on a grid between {1, 1} and {4, 4}:

```
grid = N @ Flatten[CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{{1, 1}, {4, 4}}, Into[20]], 1]
```

To evaluate f on the grid points in a vectorize way, we have to use the following syntax:

```
f @@ Transpose[grid]
```

Note that this is different from the way a `PredictorFunction` generated by `Predict` works: a predictor function can directly accept `grid` as an argument, while `InterpolationFunction`s expect the arguments in successive slots.